# postgres doesn't work inside docker container

Tags: database, postgresql, go, connection

I've been developing a webpage with golang using Postgres. I could run the app without a docker container and I could connect to the database, no problem occurred. However, when I dockerized my app and run it, Postgres showed an error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused.

Connecting to postgres:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable")
```

I searched for the internet and found that inside the container localhost will direct to the container. I tried to connect specifying the IP of my server:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=XXX.XXX.XX.XXX port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable")
```

it also showed the same error:  dial tcp XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:5432: connect: connection refused

when I run it without dockerizing it works fine.
 What to do?

Here is my dockerfile. I was just trying to upload the simplest app to the dedicated server. I logged in using ssh root@IP and installed go and postgres. I pulled my app to the server and then started it with just go build and ./app. Everything worked fine.  Now I wanna run it using the dockerfile below.

`FROM golang:alpine
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]`

Comment: you need to map your port of host to that of container, `-p 5432:5432`, while running.

Comment: @nilsocket I am using the command : `docker run -it -p 8001:8001 my_app`  to run my docker. where 8001 is the port of my app. Where I should map port 5432? sorry Im stupid but how?

Comment: You are using port 5432 when you try to open a connection to the DB, therefore you'll need to map port 5432 on your container to that port on your own machine. So like @nilsocket said do something like `docker run -it -p 5432:5432 my_app`

Comment: @darcycp you don't want to expose the DB outside of docker - so you do not want to use `-p 5432:5432`. The app inside the docker container is what needs to access the DB - this connection does not need to be exposed.

Comment: @YernarDuisebai are you using docker-compose? if the app is in one container and postgres in another - they need to be networked. Please share your Dockerfile(s) or docker-compose file.

Comment: @colm.anseo sorry your right, I thought Yenar was trying to connect to a running container with Postgres from Go code outside of the container on his local machine.

Comment: @colm.anseo, I am using Dockerfile. Added it to the post with more information about my situation. Postgres is running on my server. I also checked all credentials used to connect the posters, everything is correct.

Comment: have you tried `host=host.docker.internal`?

Comment: @YernarDuisebai add another `-p ` option as `docker run -it -p 5432:5432 -p 8001:8001 my_app` try and say it.

Comment: @nilsocket The `-p` is only used/needed for accessing ports in a container. postgres is running on the host computer - not in the container.

Comment: If you are looking to deploy this into a docker/k8s type env. I'd suggest using `docker-compose` and run both `postgres` and your `app` as containers in the same network: all the network, container hostnames, docker image names are neatly organized in one yaml config. If you must connect your docker container to the host, review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/1218512). As @Nameless suggested, `host=host.docker.internal` will work, as will many other techniques in the cited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thoroughly checking the comments by [@colm.anseo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218512/colm-anseo), I figured out how to access the host machine in the docker container. I used the flag
--network="host" to run my docker container. So I used: 
`docker run -it --network="host" myapp` to run the container. As I understood, this will
bind the IP of the docker container and host machine

you can read more about it in: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540)